# Infinite Loop in small physics based program

Tags: c, physics

Here is a program that models a tennis ball being thrown off the side of a 50 meter building.
The program should output the x, y, and velocity values at each time step.
However, I seem to be getting an infinite loop.

```
 #include<stdio.h>
 #include<math.h>

 int main() {

     //Intial values 
     float ax = 0; //acceleration in the horizontal direction
     float ay = -9.8; //acceleration in the downward direction
     float x = 0; //top of building at position 0 
     float y = 50; //building is height 50 m
     float vx = 10*cos(30); //velocity in the horizontal direction = 10 m/s * cos(30); 
     float vy = 10*sin(30); //velocity in the vertical direction = 10 m/s * sin(30);     
     int time = 0; //time starts at 0 seconds
     float deltaTime = 0.001; //increment time by .001 each iteration

     //while ball is greater than 0, or above the ground which is at position 0
     while(y > 0) {

     time = time + deltaTime;
     vx = vx + ax*deltaTime;
     vy = vy + ay*deltaTime;
     x = x + vx*deltaTime + (1/2*ax*deltaTime*deltaTime);
     y = y + vy*deltaTime + (1/2*ay*deltaTime*deltaTime);     

     printf("x = %f, y = %f, vx = %f, vy = %f, time = %d, ", x,y,vx,vy,time);

     }
     system ("PAUSE"); 
     return 0;

 }
```

My guess is that y will never become smaller than 0, but because of my limited physics knowledge, I don't know how I could fix it.

Comment: you're printing the value of y.....what do you see?

Comment: looks like time won't increment correctly. but i don't think thats the problem

Comment: Does this compile without warnings?

Comment: Another problem: `sin` [expects the angle in radians](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Math.h), but you're passing degrees.

Comment: Your time step is awfully small.  It will take thousands of iterations to reach zero.  Does y continue to decrease, once vy goes negative, does the magnitude get larger each step?  Adding: @Matt Ball, good point, it wants radians.  I don't think that's the problem, though.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

1/2 == 0 not 0.5

Since 1 and 2 are both integers this uses integer division which truncates to the closest integral number. Use `0.5f` to get a `float` or just `0.5` to get a double.

Comment: +1: There are lots of mistakes in the program, but this is the particular mistake that is causing the symptom.

Comment: Thanks and @Oli what other mistakes are there?

Comment: @kachilous: you're passing degrees to math functions that expect radians. 30° = π/6

Comment: @kachilous: Such as that `sin` and `cos` take radians, not degrees.  And that you've defined `time` as an `int` not a `float`.

Comment: Or use 1.0/2.0 as the constant fraction.

Comment: The 1/2==0 is not what the problem is. He shouldn't be adding that term anyway.

Answer (score 1):

`time` is an int, not a float; so won't that stay zero forever?

Comment: Indeed, but it's not being used in any other calculations, so it's not the issue here.

Comment: Why does that part even compile? Is `int` implicitly convertible to `float` in c?

Comment: @Code: Yes.  The compiler may issue a warning, but the language doesn't prevent it.

Answer (score 1):

Declare time as `float`, not `int`: it's not changing at all in your current code because of this.
Trigonometric functions in `<math.h>` accept *radians*, not degrees.

Comment: Indeed, but neither of these is the problem.

Comment: Yep. Note, however, that effectively nullifying the 2nd degree member in the integration does not cause the program to loop infinitely too, it simply reduces accuracy.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the term

```
y = y + vy*deltaTime + (1/2*ay*deltaTime*deltaTime);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are interested in finding out how your code, with little modification finishes without a killer loop in C#:

```
            float ax = 0; //acceleration in the horizontal direction
            float ay = -9.8f; //acceleration in the downward direction
            float x = 0; //top of building at position 0 
            float y = 50; //building is height 50 m
            float vx = 10f * (float)Math.Cos(30); //velocity in the horizontal direction = 10 m/s * cos(30); 
            float vy = 10 * (float)Math.Sin(30); //velocity in the vertical direction = 10 m/s * sin(30);     
            float time = 0; //time starts at 0 seconds
            float deltaTime = 0.001f; //increment time by .001 each iteration

            //while ball is greater than 0, or above the ground which is at position 0
            while (y > 0)
            {

                time = time + deltaTime;
                vx = vx + ax * deltaTime;
                vy = vy + ay * deltaTime;
                x = x + vx * deltaTime + (1 / 2 * ax * deltaTime * deltaTime);
                y = y + vy * deltaTime + (1 / 2 * ay * deltaTime * deltaTime);

                Console.WriteLine("x = {0}, y = {1}, vx = {2}, vy = {3}, time = {4}, ", x, y, vx, vy, time);

            }
            Console.ReadKey();
```

The only modification I did are the casts on Cos and Sin and changing time to float.
 And added the 'f' after some initial values (like casting).

It may not be a real answer for C, but it could be a clue?

Comment: This will work, but for the wrong reasons.  I'm pretty sure that `1 / 2 == 0` in C#, just like in C.